# Laravel returning empty json object with ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I have an ajax request who's calling a php function who's sorting some result and returning an Array of objects.

The return contain the results i want but when i return it back with Response::json($result) the array is well returned but with empty arrays (in the javascript).

```
public static function getResult($category = null, $artist = null, $search = null, $data)
{
    $result = [];

    if ($category != null)
    {
        if ($category < 20)
        {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value)
            {
                if (is_array($value->getCategories()))
                {
                    foreach ($value->getCategories() as $key1 => $value1)
                    {
                        if ($value1 == $category)
                        {
                            array_push($result, $value);
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                    if ($value->getCategories() == $category)
                    {
                        array_push($result, $value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($artist != null)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            if (stripos(strtolower($value->getArtist()), strtolower($artist)) !== false)
            {
                array_push($result, $value);
            }
        }
    }

    if ($search != null)
    {
        foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        {
            if (stripos(strtolower($value->getArtist()), strtolower($search)) !== false || stripos(strtolower($value->getTitle()), strtolower($search)) !== false)
            {
                array_push($result, $value);
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/browse/categories/{id}', function($id){
$result = App\Http\Controllers\browseController::getResult($id, null, null, session("TotalShop"));
// return json_encode(count($result));
return response()->json($result);
});
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".categories").click(function(event){
    $.get("/browse/categories/" + event.target.id, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

So, what can i do to get the content of my php objects in the javascript part ?

Comment: can you separate Javascript and PHP code as you have in your code or do you have the code that way in a file?

Comment: have you tried checking if it reaches the controller? tried doing `dd();` on various places and see what it throws out on chromes dev tools Network

Comment: The code are separated, i'm not very fluent with the code formating on stackoverflow the JavaScript is on the view, Php in the controller, and the route in the web.php.

Comment: It does reach the controller, the $result contain all the objects i want before the retur Response::json($result).

Comment: Have you tried to actually use  `Response::json()`? Can you post the content of `var_dump($results)`?

Comment: Yes, i got the same result, an array of empty arrays. There is the var_dump of $result before Response::json() http://pastebin.com/TfaQTeZu

Comment: @ValentinBensamon Try using `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.get()`. Make sure your browser load the updated javascript file (i.e. add some kind `console.log("update js"`)

Comment: I got the same JSON response, with the same empty arrays :(

Comment: I think i can't convert a php object to json, if i pass it to an array it works fine

Answer (score 0):

After some research, i need to pass a php Array instead of a Php Object to my Json response.